# Reshape neural network input based on condition

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

Numerical data, using DL Neural Networks. I'm using Keras library for this purpose

```
    p   u   d    ms          action B   x    y-c pre    area       finger 
0   0   36  3   1334893336790   0   1   262 262 262     0.044444    0.0
1   0   36  3   1334893336790   2   1   262 271 0.32    0.044444    0.0
2   0   36  3   1334893336795   2   1   123 327 0.28    0.044444    0.0
3   0   36  3   1334893336800   1   1   123 327 0.28    0.044444    0.0
4   0   36  3   1334893336885   0   1   216 298 0.34    0.044444    0.0
5   0   36  3   1334893336907   2   1   216 298 0.38    0.044444    0.0
6   0   36  3   1334893336926   2   1   147 312 0.60    0.088889    0.0
7   0   36  3   1334893336949   2   1   115 328 0.63    0.044444    0.0
8   0   36  3   1334893336952   2   1   98  336 0.17    0.133333    0.0
9   0   36  3   1334893336971   1   1   98  336 0.17    0.133333    0.0
1   0   36  3   1334893337798   0   1   108 339 0.48    0.044444    0.0
```

The below code is working but, as I understand neural network inputs are rowed by row as input, here I'm trying to make the input and output based on **action column** like the below example when it starts with 0 and ends with 1 then the first input for the neural network from row [0 to 3] 3 included and the second input is [4 to 9] 9 is included and etc...
The elements in the action column represent the hand movement, if the value 0 means that the finger of the hand presses on the screen, either if 1 means that the hand was lifted from the screen, so I try to divide into n number of stroke,trying to make input on neural network based on finger pressure and lifting(stroke),based on this idea input will decrease from 900k to 20k but each time the input will be multi-rows based

```
the first input will be as below:
        p   u   d    ms          action B   x    y-c pre    area       finger 
    0   0   36  3   1334893336790   0   1   262 262 262     0.044444    0.0
    1   0   36  3   1334893336790   2   1   262 271 0.32    0.044444    0.0
    2   0   36  3   1334893336795   2   1   123 327 0.28    0.044444    0.0
    3   0   36  3   1334893336800   1   1   123 327 0.28    0.044444    0.0

and the second input will be :
        p   u   d    ms          action B   x    y-c pre    area       finger 
    4   0   36  3   1334893336885   0   1   216 298 0.34    0.044444    0.0
    5   0   36  3   1334893336907   2   1   216 298 0.38    0.044444    0.0
    6   0   36  3   1334893336926   2   1   147 312 0.60    0.088889    0.0
    7   0   36  3   1334893336949   2   1   115 328 0.63    0.044444    0.0
    8   0   36  3   1334893336952   2   1   98  336 0.17    0.133333    0.0
    9   0   36  3   1334893336971   1   1   98  336 0.17    0.133333    0.0
```

here is my code and its working well in the normal cycle for NN but im trying to change it based on my idea..

```
#o = no_of_click
o=0
lenf=len(dataset)
for h in dataset.index[dataset.iloc[:, 4] == 0]:
    if dataset.iloc[h+1,4]==1 :
        dataset.iloc[h+1,4]=-1
        dataset.iloc[h , 4] = -1
        o=o+1
dataset=dataset.drop(dataset[dataset.iloc[:, 4] == -1].index)
lenf=(o*2)
X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:].values #here 3to 11 for x
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values #here user id 2 only y

binariz = LabelBinarizer()
s = binariz.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
X = np.delete(X, [0], axis=1)
X = np.hstack([s,X])
y = binariz.fit_transform(y)
# X Features scaling
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

# Splitting Data
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

classifier = Sequential()
# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, activation = 'relu', input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))
# Adding the second hidden layer

classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, activation = 'relu'))
# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = y.shape[1], activation = 'softmax'))
# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 100, epochs = 10)
```

Comment: off topic - I see you deleted your TAP3 question - I'm still happy to help if you would like at some point in the future.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you brother , i have solved the problem thats why, you are great person <3

Comment: mashro3ak, glad to hear it!  Would you be willing to undelete your question and post your solution as an answer?  That way it can help other people who might have a similar problem.  (Plus you can get some reputation from upvotes on your question or answer. :) )  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer .  Up to you, of course!  (Thanks for the kind words, as well!)

Comment: i have post the soulation as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly; apologies in advance if I'm making incorrect assumptions.

It seems to me that you are asking whether you can reshape the input vector so in one case it has shape=(4,) and in the other shape=(6,).

I don't believe you can, since when you add a Dense layer after an input layer this Dense layer has a weights matrix that is shaped as (input_dims, output_dims). This is selected when the graph is built.

Even if you could, I don't think you would want to.
The input vector to a NN is a set of features; it seems that in your case this is a set of different measurements. You don't want to feed the network with measurement of feature0 in the input tensor position 0 in one scenario and measurement of feature4 in another scenario. That makes it much harder for the network to understand how to process these values.

Given that you have a small set of features, is there any reason you don't just pass all the data all the time ?

Comment: The elements in the action column represent the hand movement, if the value 0 means that the finger of the hand presses on the screen, either if 1 means that the hand was lifted from the screen, so I try to divide into n number of stroke,trying to make input on neural network based on finger pressure and lifting(stroke),based on this idea input will decrease from 900k to 20k but each time the input will be multi-rows based as discussed , i will update my question please check after while